# issue displaying svg image in Xamarin Forms with nuget package

Tags: xaml, svg, xamarin.forms

Has anyone who has used any of the nugget packages to render svg images in xamarin forms come across an error similar to

System.NotSupportedException:   Path Operation l

I seem to get this where the svg is 'bigger', as in there is more xml to it than simpler images.

Comment: `l` could be a path command [relative lineto](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataLinetoCommands) - maybe inclomplete support for SVG?

Comment: I believe the exception says it all; not supported. Check with the original author and/or on the Github repository.

Comment: Both comments make sense - it's when the svg has more than one <path> element that it breaks.  We're going to try generating them in Sketch, but failing that does anyone know if it's possible to re-create multiple-path svg's as single-path?  thanks

Comment: Update for anyone who might need this - creating the svg in Sketch produced images which, although had multiple paths, were usable.

Comment: Use this: https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ to make your SVGs simpler